# How to get the values from individual columns in an SQL Database with Java: UcanaccessSQLException

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sqlexception, ucanaccess

I have a table in a database which I have displayed in a JTable on a JFrame. I made the connection to the database and everything displays perfectly when I run the program. When I try to get the values of individual fields using `getInt` and `getString` methods it doesn't work and I run into errors.

In my main method I call

`msConnectDB(tblDatabase, "SELECT * FROM tblGeneral");`

The `msConnectDB` method is as follows:

```
public void msConnectDB(JTable tbl, String query){
        try{
            if(query != null){
                Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

                // a connection is established without any errors and the query is called successfully
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C://Users//...//MyDB.accdb");
                Statement st = connection.createStatement();
                resultSet = st.executeQuery(query);
         
                // the resultSet is displayed in the table
                tbl.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet));
                
                // this does not return anything
                System.out.println(DbUtils.resultSetToNestedList(resultSet));
                
                // this does not print anything
                while(resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.print(resultSet.getInt("ID"));
                    System.out.print(resultSet.getDate("DateReported"));
                    System.out.print(resultSet.getDouble("Price"));
                    System.out.print(resultSet.getInt("Style"));
                    System.out.print(resultSet.getInt("OriginID"));
                    System.out.print(resultSet.getInt("DestinationID"));
                    
                }
            }
            else{
                tbl.removeAll();
            }
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

When I call `System.out.println(DbUtils.resultSetToNestedList(resultSet))` it returns an empty list `[]`

Nothing else is printed other than `[]`

The table is drawn in `tbl.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet));`  and looks like this:

[image]

Before the JFrame is displayed I get the following error in a message dialog:

`netucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.1 invalid cursor state: identifier cursor not positioned on row in UPDATE, DELETE, SET, or GET statement: ; ResultSet is positioned after last row`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *it returns an empty list []* That's because you've already used up the `ResultSet` on `resultSetToTableModel`. Out of interest, where did you find `DbUtils`?